# How to POST data to website api using httprequest or httpclient

Tags: c#

I trying to Post to this api : https://api.golike.net:9998/api/job  . And print the result api give back

Type json of that api is :

```
{"user":`{"id":37,"username":"lucky","counter_rechecking":0,"user_id":761,"fb_id":"100047460285611"}}
```

Can anyone help me . there is already data and type data . Thanks For Help . You can help me post using **HttpRequest** or **HttpClient**

Comment: Your `Json` format is incorrect.  **Remove** `'` after `{"user":`

Comment: have you tried to test this api by postman for example?

Comment: yes but idk how to post it in C# beaucse it have USER then ID

Comment: i just can post ID . but dont know how to post ID in USER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
 private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(string uri, object input)
    {
        var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var client = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(YourBaseApiAddress)
        };

        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {               
            var newResponse = await Post(uri, input, Authentication);
            return newResponse;
        }
        return response;
    }
```

and for your response

```
 var response = Post(uri, yourObject).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var value = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                   
            }
```

Comment: where is RequestJwtToken()

Comment: the input is the object you want to post. if you want to use the json you have you will need to remove the new stringContent line because this line converts the object to json.

Comment: I removed the other line you asked me,i forgot it from my code.